# Requesting help getting VS Code debugger for Python to work with Anaconda

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I'm able to use the VS Code debugger for Python as expected with simple base library code, but when I try to use pandas, I'm getting import errors when debugging. According to the [VS Code docs on environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_choosing-an-environment), the debugger should default to using my interpreter/distribution set in user settings, which is Anaconda. Below are links to screenshots of the error and launch.json:

[vs code debugger error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G6JM.png)
[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhRxx.png)

All I've been able to determine from my searching similar threads is that others in this situation had different settings unique to them that kept the debugger from using Anaconda with the debugger. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming numpy is installed, make sure to launch VS Code from your activated conda environment (conda wants to own the environment it works in, so VS Code needs to already have it set up to make some imports work).

Comment: Thank you sir, this did the trick. I'm trying to run VS Code with WSL as my default terminal, on Windows 10, with Anaconda as the default interpreter. Makes life interesting.